# Как в генераторе создать такую матрицу?

Tags: python

```
matrix = [

[1,2,3,4,5],
[6,7,8,9,10],
[11,12,13,14,15],
[16,17,18,19,20],
[21,22,23,24,25]

]
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К примеру, можно таким образом:

```
gen = ([i+5*j for i in range(1,6)] for j in range(0, 5))
print(list(gen))
```

Вывод:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

Или просто список делаем:

```
list_1 = [[i+5*j for i in range(1,6)] for j in range(0, 5)]
print(list_1)
```

Вывод построчно:

```
print(*list_1, sep='\n')
```

Comment: спасибо большое! А как вывести её в виде матрицы как в вопросе?

Comment: А зачем вы используете генераторное сокращение, если всё-равно его потом в список превращаете? Используйте тогда сразу списковое сокращение.

Comment: Так генератор просили)

Comment: @AndyPavlov Ах да. Но это какой-то бред получается )  Ладно

Comment: @indian_girl более подробную информацию можете найти https://python-scripts.com/loops-for-while